# how to submit review form with postman or orther service on github?

Tags: github, browser, postman

I am building a tool that it will help me approve PR github. But I am stucking at submit form step.
[image]
I don't know what I'm missing, please help me!

With `f12`, I have name and action of form review:
[image]

And the below is my postman params:
[image]
[image]
(cookie is user_session's value at application tab)

when I send request, response status is 422, I think I'm missing something, can you help me to solve it?